# WAMP + RewriteRule : Copying site to subfolder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

I've just installed WAMP, and now I'm trying to copy my files from my server to my local machine. I have a rewrite rule like

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

But that seems to redirect to `http://localhost/index.php` when I actually want `http://localhost/mysite/index.php`. So I figured

```
RewriteBase /mysite
```

Would do the trick, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Doesn't seem to work that way from my readings. Is there any way that I can fix this without changing my rewrite rules? I basically just want the base of my site to be in some subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by having a trailing slash on the RewriteBase string:

```
RewriteBase /aliasdirectory/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you’re using relative paths in your substitution, you don’t need to alter the base URI path:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think this causes problems when the user is in a sub-sub-folder. i.e. if they're at /mysite/folder/page it should still point to /mysite/index.php?url=/folder/page

Comment: (rather than /mysite/folder/index.php?url=whatever)